# Problem with urllib source code in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, jython

I am having a bizarre problem in which Eclipse is raising an error for the source code of a python Lib package. I am using Python 3.7.1.

The relevant line is:

```
import urllib.request.urlopen as uReq
```

I don't believe the python interpreter I'm using is relevant to this particular problem. Nevertheless, here is the code for it. (I know, it's probably horrendous. If you know a better way to do this, please kindly point me in the right direction; this is my first time using jython and I'm sure it shows.)

```
interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys");
interpreter.exec("import os");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + '\\src\\python')");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + '\\Lib')");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + '\\Lib\\site-packages')");
interpreter.exec("print(sys.path[0])");
interpreter.exec("from myscraper import validateUrl");
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\...\ThreadTracker\src\python\myscraper.py", line 6, in <module>
import urllib.request.urlopen as uReq
SyntaxError: ("mismatched input ',' expecting NAME", 
('C:\\Users\\...\\ThreadTracker\\Lib\\urllib\\request.py', 140, 13, '            
*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None):\n'))
```

Which seems to be having a problem with this line of code from the source file:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        *, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None):
```

I saw on another post that urllib3 could be used as well, so I tried:

from urllib3 import request as uReq

But this came up with its own error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Christina\ThreadTracker\src\python\myscraper.py", line 6, in <module>
from urllib3 import request as uReq
File "C:\Users\Christina\ThreadTracker\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Users\Christina\ThreadTracker\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
import logging
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input '='", ('C:\\Users\\Christina\\ThreadTracker\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py', 261, 55, '                      method_name, "method:", err, file=sys.stderr)\n'))
```

I'm extremely confused as to why I'm getting errors from the source code... And I've been having a heck of a time just trying to get the java-python integration to work.

Comment: Jython doesn't have language-level support for Python3.

Comment: So would I have to downgrade my Python version to 2.something to get this to work? Is there another option available for Java-Python integration that will work for Python3?

Comment: Correct.  As far as I know, that is the state of things.